# iPhone app interruptions not being reported to app correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, interruption

This is a fringe usage case, but it poses a good question. Here you go:

I'm developing a game for iPhone in which I need to pause the game when interruptions occur.  I use the interrupt handlers `applicationWillResignActive:` `applicationDidEnterBackground:`  `applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` to pause and resume my game, save game progress, etc, as you would expect.

I'm having trouble in the following scenario:

1. Game is running, and I do a multitasking interrupt (double click home button).
2. `applicationWillResignActive:` is called, game suspends, all is awesome.
3. Then, with the multitasking bar open, I do a triple home click interrupt (see Settings->General->Accessiblity->Triple Home Click  and select the 'Ask' option).  An options popup slides in over the top of the multitasking bar, no interrupt handlers are called in the app.
4. I cancel the options popup.  `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is called, the game resumes while the multitasking bar is still open. This is strange.
5. I close the multitasking bar with another home button double click, no interrupt handlers are called.

What in Sam Hill is going on here???  I have seen other games (like Spy Mouse for example) that seem to handle this same series of interruptions correctly. Does anyone out there know if there is another way to catch system events from the OS, and thereby be able to handle interruptions with greater precision?  That, or am I missing something obvious?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!